# ¿Cómo buscar por ID usando un procedimiento almacenado?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net, stored-procedure

Soy nuevo en store procedures y quiero buscar por id y despues mostrar los datos en un grid. simple

Tengo un textbox donde inserto un id entero y la idea es que en el codigo de .net, mandar a llamar el store procedure y el store procedure busque por id el producto y me traiga los datos coincidan, tengo esto:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CAOE_BUSCAR
SELECT Title, Nombre, Description,Observations, PriceDistributor
from Products where Id =
```

Pero tengo la duda de como poner una variable en el valor de id ya que el id siempre variara depende lo que meta en el textbox

Comment: Ya revisaste [la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: ¿Ya probaste concatenar el valor del textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declara el SP que reciba un parametro asi:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CAOE_BUSCAR(@ID INTEGER)
AS BEGIN
  SELECT Title, Nombre, Description,Observations, PriceDistributor
  from Products where Id = @ID
END
```

Donde @ID es el parametro que le enviaras para que filtres.

Aqui un ejemplo de como ejecutarlo:

```
CAOE_BUSCAR(33) // retornara el resultado de la busqueda
```

Un SP puede tener cuantos parametros necesite, solo tienes que tener en cuenta el tipo de dato del parametro:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE CAOE_BUSCAR(@ID INTEGER, @nombre VARCHAR(400))
    AS BEGIN
      SELECT Title, Nombre, Description,Observations, PriceDistributor
      from Products where Id = @ID
    END

CAOE_BUSCAR(44,'HOLA')
```

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso yo lo hice asi en c#
string cn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WsdP"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn = null;

```
        conn = new SqlConnection(cn);
        
        conn.Open();

        string sql = "select * from UserSist WHERE idsist = @idsist";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idsist", idsist);


        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows){
        }else{
        }
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente el funcionamiento del código. Recuerda que [es.so] no es un repositorio de código. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.